How is じゃない used after a verb without the　か?

はあ、部下が真面目だと私が不真面目に見えるじゃない。やだあ

"If my subordinates are serious, then I.... I hate that"
Is じゃない here giving a negative nuance? How is different from みえない?

じゃない here is identical to じゃないか, but slightly softer and less masculine. It has more of an emotional nuance than simply saying 見えない？
'If my subordinates are so serious, it'll look like I'm not, won't it?! Gah!'
